# R - dplyr - returning true/false (or similar) from left_join call

Tags: r, dplyr

If I have two data frames x and y...

`x` has columns col1, col2, col3, col4, ...
`y` has columns col1 and col2

I want to know which records in x find a match in y (ie I look up the two fields with the same name in both tables, and a match is found). I tried to do this via left_join but using the horribly ugly:

```
y$flag = 12345 # or 1 or TRUE or anything at all really
x <- x %>% left_join(y, by = c("col1" = "col1", "col2" = "col2")
```

I'm sure there's a more elegant way to do this but I'm not knowledgeable enough here. Can anyone suggest a better way please?

Thank you.

Comment: To better help you can you include a reproducible example using `dput` along with expected output ?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to basically filter your `x`-data based on the `y`-data you can use `semi_join()` (keeping x when matches in y) or `anti_join()` (dropping x when there are matches in y). these are also known as filter join methods.

```
x <- x %>% anti_join(y, by = c("col1" = "col1", "col2" = "col2")
```

---

From the help page:

*`anti_join()`:
return all rows from x where there are not matching values in y, keeping just columns from x.*

However, for debugging purposes, I often use your `y$flag <- TRUE`-left-join-method.

---

*edited according to the comment from OP*

Comment: Thank you. I should have explained more fully: I do want to retain the rows of x where no match is found (hence using left_join() specifically), in which case I don’t think (?) semi_join will work here. My mistake.

Comment: then you can use anti_join. Uodated my answer

Comment: won’t I then lose the records of x where a match *is* found? I want to retain every row of x (whether or not a match is found). Apologies - again I could have been more explicit about that.

Comment: I dont get your point. What do you expect from a solution when you already have a solution? Note that 'good coding practice' or 'best style' questions are off-topic on SO.

Comment: Ok. I wasn’t aware of that. Duly noted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an alternative way to create the named vector for the `by` criteria with `intersect`.

```
x <- x %>%
  left_join(y, by = setNames(intersect(colnames(x), colnames(y)),
                             intersect(colnames(x), colnames(y))))
```

Not sure if it is less ugly though. And this is what `dplyr` will basically do by default anyways (but with a message).